# Regex : catch one character but not more

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to find a regexp that catches all instances that contain one and only one `\n` and any number of  (space), in a string that might also contain instances with multiple `\n`. So, for instance (with spaces denoted with `_`):

```
Should be caught:
\n
_\n
\n_
_\n_

Should *not* be caught, not even the first \n:
_
___
\n\n\n\n
\n\n\n_\n\n
_\n\n
\n\n_
_\n\n_
_\n\n_\n
\n_\n_
_\n_\n
_\n\n_\n_
___\n__\n and so on...
```

(Using `re` in `pyton3` on `Windows10`)
I'm trying to find a regexp that catches all instances that contain one and only one `\n` and any number of  (space), in a string that might also contain instances with multiple `\n`. So, for instance (with spaces denoted with `_`):

```
Should be caught:
\n
_\n
\n_
_\n_

Should *not* be caught, not even the first \n:
_
___
\n\n\n\n
\n\n\n_\n\n
_\n\n
\n\n_
_\n\n_
_\n\n_\n
\n_\n_
_\n_\n
_\n\n_\n_
___\n__\n and so on...
```

(Using `re` in `pyton3` on `Windows10`)

---

**Edit** to clarify the context: I'm parsing the text of a web page and I have a block of text in a string, that looks like that:

> Word word word. Word word word word word. **\n** Word word word word word word. Word word word word. **\n\n \n**Word word word word word. **\n**Word word word. Word word word.

In the subsequent steps of my code, I'm using a function that gets rid of any `\n`, so I want to detect where they are before using this function, so I can keep them (by replacing them temporarily with special characters that won't disappear). But as you can see, I have two cases :

1) Multiple `\n` indicate a break of paragraphs, but I have no way to be sure that they follow each other without spaces or tabs between them. I want to catch them to replace them with a special character (like `§` for instance) that will let me know later where to put back multiple `\n`. It only matters that I know there are 2 or more `\n`, not how many there are. At the moment, I'm using this (but please do tell me if there is a bug):

```
text = re.sub(r"[ \t]*(?:\n[ \t]*){2,}", "$", text)
```

2) Single `\n` indicate a line break within a paragraph. These are what I want to single out, without catching the instances of the previous case. Again, it's to replace them with a special character (say `|`) to put it back later:

```
text = re.sub(r"   the_regex_I'm_looking_for      ", "|", text)
```

(I know I could do the first replacement, and then search for the remaining `\n`, but for reasons that would be largely irrelevant here and long to explain, I can't.)

**2nd edit**: So, for instance, the desired result in this case would be:

> Word word word. Word word word word word. **|** Word word word word word word. Word word word word. **$** Word word word word word. **|** Word word word. Word word word.

(I'd rather have no spaces before and after the `§` and the `|`, but here I'm forced to put them for the **bold** formatting of StackOverflow, if I don't I get something like **$**that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following pattern suit you?

```
import regex as re
StrVal = r'Word word word. Word word word word word. \n Word word word word word word. Word word word word. \n\n \nWord word word word word. \nWord word word. Word word word.'
StrVal = re.sub(r'(?<!\\n\s*)\s*\\n\s*(?!\s*\\n)', '|', StrVal)
print(StrVal)
```

Returns:

```
Word word word. Word word word word word.|Word word word word word word. Word word word word. \n\n \nWord word word word word.|Word word word. Word word word.
```

So instead of `re` module, I referenced [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module to make use of non-fixed width quantifier in the negative lookbehind, something `re` would not allow. So also patterns like `\n \n\n \n` get *no* substitution.

Comment: I'm trying it out, but so far it seems to be working, thanks! Holy cow regexes are complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo whether it is ok for you. I have used space instead of "_".

```
import re
pattern = '^ *\n *$'
test_string = "\n\n "
result = re.findall(pattern, test_string)
print(result)
```

NB: I used '^\s*\n\s*' but it will not work as \s is equivalent to [\t\n\r\f\v]. so I have used space ' ' character